# How to enlarge and widen the photo as it can in ms word?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

my program :

produce a picture that is extracting data from excel .

Paste it in word and make the page setting as Landscape .

However ,the picture generated is small and the setting of page become custom.

the photo is so wide .I don't want to enlarge by myself everytimes.

How can I add this setting in vba ?Make it as large and wide as it can .

Secondly , it is pleasure that the data extracted can be pasted as table format.

my codes :

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim tbl0 As Excel.RANGE
    Dim Tbl As Excel.RANGE
    Dim tbl2 As Excel.RANGE

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("17-18")             ' Change e.g. sheet9.Name
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

Value1 = Me.TextBox1.Value
Value2 = Me.TextBox2.Value
    ws.Rows("84:89").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'ADJUST AS APPROPRIATE

    'Copy Range from Excel
    'Set tbl0 = ws.RANGE("A78:I83")
    Set Tbl = ws.RANGE("A78:I92")


    ' Set tbl2 = ws.Range("A90:I92")

    'Create an Instance of MS Word
    On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
    Set wordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then Set wordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    'Make MS Word Visible and Active
    wordApp.Visible = True
    wordApp.Activate

    'Create a New Document
    Set myDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add

    'Trigger copy separately for each table + paste for each table

    Tbl.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    wordApp.Selection.Paste
    wordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

    wordApp.Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape

    resize_all_images_to_page_width myDoc

EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't fiddle with Word but Excel only it might give you an idea...

The code of my XmasPrep excel sucks in a bunch of pictures in order to produce a catalog, listing the pictures to select from.

[image]

For each line, i.e. each picture, the code

- assigns an Excel cell range and then resizes the range ROW height and width
  as well as the range height itself
- assigns the picture object thisPic = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(picFileName) and then resizes that according to the cell range's coordinates and size:

  ```
  thisPic.Top = .Top + 1
  thisPic.Left = .Left + 1
  thisPic.Width = .Width - 2
  thisPic.Height = .Height - 2
  ```

So, if you're able to grab the picture object (thisPic) in Word you might be able to resize it to your needs as well. Hope it helps.

```
    :
    Const MaxHeight = 50
    Const MaxWidth = 14
    Dim picFileName         As String
    Dim i, j, k             As Long
    Dim col_Filenames       As Long
    Dim col_Pictures        As Long
    Dim range_PicCell       As Range
    Dim thisPic             As Picture
    :

    picFileName = filesPath & select2order.Cells(i, col_Filenames).Value
    Set range_PicCell = select2order.Cells(i, col_Pictures)
    range_PicCell.RowHeight = MaxHeight
    range_PicCell.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth
    With range_PicCell
        .Height = MaxHeight
        Set thisPic = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(picFileName)
        thisPic.Top = .Top + 1
        thisPic.Left = .Left + 1
        thisPic.Width = .Width - 2
        thisPic.Height = .Height - 2
    End With
    :
```

Comment: Quite cool answer, but the op is copying the picture to Word.

Comment: yep, true. But if the code can grab the picture object after pasting it and knows the frame size of word, then...

Comment: or is it more convenient to extract the table  into table format from excel and  and best fit the size in word doc later?